# How can I get the raw binary content from an arbitrary typed QVariant into a QBytearray?

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, binary-data, qvariant

### Problem

I have an interface which gives me a `QVariant` of an arbitrary type. I need to convert the data content in this variant to a raw binary `QByteArray`:

```
QVariant result = myQVariantReturningMethod(type arg, type arg2);
QByteArray rawResult = ?;
```

### Background

The resulting `QByteArray` is sent over Canbus. Depending on its size, it is transmitted in several can frames or in a single one. The can bus interface for sending frames takes a `QByteArray` as input. Based on additional information, the receiver of the can frames knows how to parse the incoming stream of can frames.

### What I tried so far

I tried several approaches

- Using a `QDataStream` to get the data into the array. However the serialization works in an unpredictable way, where I always get additional information about the type itself in the resulting array, depending of the implementation of the `<</>>` operators for the type.
- Using `toString().toStdString()` of the `QVariant`, resulting in a casted value, not the actual binary raw data which is not what I want.
- Using `toBytearryay()`, resulting in the same.

I do not care whether an `stl` way or a `qt` way is a possible approach to the problem. However, It has to be `c++11`-compatible

Comment: As presented this looks like a xy-problem.  Can you provide some details as to how you plan to use the resulting `QByteArray`?

Comment: Elaborated in the initial question.

Comment: Do you still miss something in my elaboration?

Comment: I can't see any way to directly place a `QVariant` into a `QByteArray`.  Personally I'd go with the `QDataStream` method you've already tried: encode to a `QByteArray` using `QDataStream` on the sender and decode from the `QByteArray` via `QDataStream` at the receiver.

Comment: This would require that the receiver knows about qt, which it does not. Furthermore, it would increase the bus load a lot on the can bus, due to the overhead. Even if I tell the receiver how to properly parse the bytes that are stored in the sender side qdatastream, I have no influence on the receiver implementation. Nonetheless thanks for your effort.

Comment: In that case I think the only option is to decode the `QVariant` returned by `myQVariantReturningMethod` on the senders side and write that into a `QByteArray` based on the actual type contained within it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that `QVariant` has an undocumented method `constData()` which gives exactly the result I want to have: A pointer to the internally stored data of the `QVariant`. Together with `QMetaType::sizeOf()`, this is exactly what is needed to write all the data into a `QByteArray`.

I found that method documented in the documentation of `Qt 6.0` and found it as well working with my `Qt 5.12.7`, despite not being described in the corresponding documentation.